# Get Username of Tumblr

Tags: php, tumblr

http://username.tumblr.com/api/read/json

For Tumblr, we need username and we can get info about that user but my requirement is to first get a person logged in tumblr and then get its username. Is it possible. I have already searched a lot but nothing is working. I got oauth installed, still it is not working. 
Now, i am using the following link for reference,
https://github.com/bungle/web.php/blob/master/tumblr.php

I want to get login and then get username

```
$client=new tumblr('theamanjotkaurworld.tumblr.com','123','234','234','432');
echo $client->authorize('http://xyz.abc.com');
```

Comment: You can only get the `username` for the currently authorised user? https://github.com/bungle/web.php/blob/master/tumblr.php#L81

Comment: sorry @mikedidthis, I didn't understand

Comment: Then how can I do the above functionality without using Oauth

Comment: You can get the authorised users name using the method `user()`. That will return an object with a key called `name` which is the `username`. https://www.tumblr.com/docs/en/api/v2#user-methods

Comment: i dont know how to use oauth. can u please guide me @mikedidthis

Comment: i want to get data at login time @mikedidthis